Deciphering a courthouse note from 1611
In a courthouse book from 1611 I've found an entry related to my home village. Since it is written in Latin, with lots of abbreviations and legal terms, I have troubles translating it...  Could someone help me in deciphering this text into full Latin words/sentences, so that it will be possible for me to translate it?
It is about some legal dispute between parish priest of Mszana (a village in southern Poland) and Anna Belinowa, the owner of that village.
Here is the scan of that book (I also attach images at the end of this post):

RCC 37, p. 1484-1485

And here are the results I've got so far (probably – with lots of errors); I've marked abbreviations in parentheses and "X" means that I had no idea what the letter(s) might be:
p. 1484
(...) per v(e)n(er)abilem Ioannem Frenczkowicz
parochum Mszanen(sis) pro parte sua literas infraseras sacrXX
RegiXX Mltis vady partes XXX interpersiti
sigillo Regni minor cancellaris obsignat quarum tenor
est talis.
(...). Magnifice syncere nobi(li)s dilecte
expesitum nobis est nomine v(e)n(er)abilis Ioannis Franczkowicz
paroch Mszanensis quod illi generosa Anna Belinowa subdapiferatrix
Cracovien(sis) tam per se famulos suos quam per subordinatas 
personas, magnas minXXas facit et apertas inimieitias in
vitXX ipsius discrimen denuntiat, ita ut abilla seeums esse non
possit. Quod nos non modo tranquillitati communi verum et 
legibus Regni contrarium esse existimen volumus ut partes
eisdem non vi et ermis per seae famulos suos sed iure mediante
seeum agXX vadiumXX prepterea nostrum decem millium
floren polonicat inter eaX interponend esse duximus,
interpoXXX hisce literis aparte illi contranenien ei cui intererit 
persolnenXX. Quod si vero partrum aliqua bona vadio huic XX equivalentia

p. 1485
non habuerit de solnen eo parenXX iuri per idoneob
fide iussores caneat, ne autem partes supraseres ignorantiam 
eius prettendant, volumus ut vadium hic in Acta Cap(ita)nealia
Castren(sis) Cracovien(sis) inscribi et per minialem terrem in domos
eamnX partium defeni, et ad notifiam deduci curat. (...)


